# Unable to add custom site config to Silverstripe 4

Tags: php, yaml, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Im following the [original docs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/configuration/siteconfig/) but `/dev/build` is not generating the db fields and the form fields are not getting generated either.

this is the value of my `app/_config/app.yml`

```
---
Name: myproject
---
SilverStripe\Core\Manifest\ModuleManifest:
  project: app
---
Silverstripe\SiteConfig\SiteConfig:
  extensions:
    - CustomSiteConfig
---
SilverStripe\Admin\LeftAndMain:
  extra_requirements_css:
    - public/resources/admin/css/custom.css
```

and this is my `app/src/extensions/CustomSiteConfig.php`

```
<?php

use SilverStripe\Forms\FieldList;
use SilverStripe\Forms\HTMLEditor\HTMLEditorField;
use SilverStripe\ORM\DataExtension;

class CustomSiteConfig extends DataExtension
{

    private static $db = [
        'FooterContent' => 'HTMLText'
    ];

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields)
    {
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main",
            new HTMLEditorField("FooterContent", "Footer Content")
        );
    }
}
```

Silverstripe is new to me and maybe I'm missing something here. But I'm looking for an hour now and cant get it to work.

Comment: Perhaps you need to `?flush`

Comment: @RobbieAverill sorry, i forgot to mention that. I‘ve cleared all Cache variants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in the way you're structuring your YAML:

```
---
Name: myproject
---
SilverStripe\Core\Manifest\ModuleManifest:
  project: app
---
Silverstripe\SiteConfig\SiteConfig:
  extensions:
    - CustomSiteConfig
---
SilverStripe\Admin\LeftAndMain:
  extra_requirements_css:
    - public/resources/admin/css/custom.css
```

The `---` blocks are notating title blocks for each section of config, so the dividers you're using after the section with `Name: myproject` in it are creating more title blocks which won't be treated as config any more.

Try this:

```
---
Name: myproject
---
SilverStripe\Core\Manifest\ModuleManifest:
  project: app

Silverstripe\SiteConfig\SiteConfig:
  extensions:
    - CustomSiteConfig

SilverStripe\Admin\LeftAndMain:
  extra_requirements_css:
    - public/resources/admin/css/custom.css
```